# Algorithm for value range mapping

Tags: algorithm, mapping, range

My question perhaps belongs to general ability test or something like that. It is **not** directly related to Embedded devices.

I have been given a variable resister which can rotate infinitely and is of `10Ω`. ADC is set for value range 0 to 1023 sampling. By which I've to control light luminosity/intensity.

The ADC value range is divided into 32 steps for `1024/32` levels of brightness. The issue is the pot has to be rotated 16 times to get to extremities. Which is very harassing. Now its time when I can't change the pot hardware but the firmware.

I thought of doing as follows, please help me from here:

I'll choose a range window within the [0 1023], say of 32 steps. Lets ignore the ADC noise for now.

Then we have 32 steps in that 32 step windows.

If I start from 0, the intensity will be increasing till 32. The 32 is max intensity possible. Then if I rotate more, the intensity should remain maximum at 32 all the way till 1023.

And as soon as it is started to decrease from 1023, I will have decrease in intensity till ( 1023-32 ) and will remain at 0 intensity all the way till 0.

- if I rotate back from any place it should follow the above explained moving window rule.

How to start with it?

---

Pseudo code:

```
void processADC_data()
 {
        ushort adc0 = (ushort)ADC_DATA;
        adc0_Avg = adc0;

        // If Noise 
        /*
        ushort adc0_L = (ushort)(adc0 - 40);
        ushort adc0_H = (ushort)(adc0 + 40);

        adc0 = (ushort)read_ADC( adc0_L,adc0_H );

        adc0_Avg = adc0 * 20 + adc0_Avg * 80;
        adc0_Avg /= 100;
        */

        IsInceasing = (adc0_last - adc0_Avg) < 0 ;
        adc0_last = adc0_Avg;



        if (IsInceasing)
        {

            // Extrimity has to be handled 
            if (!HasPerformedIncreased)
            {
                adc0_center = (ushort)(adc0_Avg - window);
                HasPerformedIncreased = true;
                HasPerformedDecrease = false;
            }
            else if (HasPerformedIncreased)
            {
                IsCrossingLimit = ( (adc0_Avg - adc0_center) > window );
                if(IsCrossingLimit)
                {
                    adc0_Avg = LIGHT_SENS_MAX;
                    IsCrossingLimit = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    adc0_Avg = (ushort)(adc0_Avg / LIGHT_SENS_MAX);
                }
            }

            //judge_brightness(adc0_Avg);
        }
        else
        {
            // Extrimity has to be handled 
            if (!HasPerformedDecrease)
            {
                adc0_center = (ushort)(adc0_Avg + window);
                HasPerformedDecrease = true;
                HasPerformedIncreased = false;
            }
            else if (HasPerformedDecrease)
            {
                IsCrossingLimit = ( (adc0_center - adc0_Avg) > window );
                if(IsCrossingLimit)
                {
                    adc0_Avg = LIGHT_SENS_MIN;
                    IsCrossingLimit = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    adc0_Avg = (ushort)(adc0_Avg / LIGHT_SENS_MAX);
                }
            }


        }

            brightness(adc0_Avg);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You might get better answers over at [electronics.se](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Posted it there with irrelevant tags. Didn't find any. thanks. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42507/algorithm-for-value-range-mapping

Comment: @jurgemaister in future, please don't encourage cross-posting of questions, just flag for a mod to review and migrate. Thanks.

Comment: All right @Kev I'll keep that in mind.